# smooth-scrollbar.js - Disable scroll when fullscreen menu open, activate when menu closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

As per the title, I am using smooth-scrollbar.js along with this fullscreen menu. Currently when you click the button to open the menu, you can still scroll the page, im trying to disable scrolling when the menu is opened and then re-enable scrolling when the menu is closed. I have been reading on forums online and someone suggested using "scrollbar.destroy()" but I have not been able to accomplish what i need using this, maybe i used it incorrectly.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to accomplish this, that would be great!

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('#burger')

const tl = gsap.timeline()

tl.to('.menu-link', {
  translateY: '100%',
  duration: 0.5,
})

tl.to('.menu-overlay', {
  width: '0'
})


burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  tl.reversed(!tl.reversed());
})
```

```css
:root {
  --zIndex-overlay: 900;
  --zIndex-navbar: 905;
  --colors-text: white;
  --colors-background: black;
  --colors-contast: #f4e285;
}
body {
  color: var(--colors-text);
  background-color: #304a36;
  font-family: "Prompt", sans-serif;
  font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-text-decoration: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
.menu-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: var(--zIndex-overlay);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.menu-content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-color: var(--colors-background);
}
.menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
.menu-list li {
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-link {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.menu-link:hover {
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
}
.menu-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10% 10%;
}
.menu-footer span {
  color: var(--colors-contast);
}
.title {
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu-social-links {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-block: 0.4em 0.7em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu-social-links a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 786px) {
  .menu-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
button[id='burger'] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu-overlay'>
  <div class='menu-content'>
    <ul class='menu-list'>
      <li>
        <a href='' class='menu-link title'>About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='' class='menu-link title'>Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='' class='menu-link title'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<button id='burger'>Burger</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 import Scrollbar, { ScrollbarPlugin } from 'smooth-scrollbar';

 class ModalPlugin extends ScrollbarPlugin {
  static pluginName = 'modal';

  static defaultOptions = {
    open: false,
  };

  transformDelta(delta) {
    return this.options.open ? { x: 0, y: 0 } : delta;
  }
}

Scrollbar.use(ModalPlugin);

const options = {
  delegateTo: document,
  damping: 0.05,
  continuousScrolling: false,
};

const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

const scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(wrapper, options);
```

And toggle the scrollbar state where you need it:

```
scrollbar.updatePluginOptions('modal', { open: false }); // true, false
```

Answer (score 0):

just added some css trick in this case, added `burgerOpen` this class to body element

```
body.burgerOpen {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try below demo

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('#burger')

const tl = gsap.timeline()

tl.to('.menu-link', {
    translateY: '100%',
    duration: 0.5,
})

tl.to('.menu-overlay', {
    width: '0'
})


burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    tl.reversed(!tl.reversed());
    $('body').toggleClass('burgerOpen');
})
```

```css
:root {
    --zIndex-overlay: 900;
    --zIndex-navbar: 905;
    --colors-text: white;
    --colors-background: black;
    --colors-contast: #f4e285;
}
body {
    color: var(--colors-text);
    background-color: #304a36;
    font-family: "Prompt", sans-serif;
    font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-text-decoration: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
.menu-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: var(--zIndex-overlay);
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.menu-content {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    background-color: var(--colors-background);
}
.menu-list {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
.menu-list li {
    width: fit-content;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-link {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.menu-link:hover {
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
}
.menu-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10% 10%;
}
.menu-footer span {
    color: var(--colors-contast);
}
.title {
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu-social-links {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-block: 0.4em 0.7em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu-social-links a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 786px) {
    .menu-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
button[id='burger'] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
body{
    height: 1500px;
}
body.burgerOpen {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu-overlay'>
    <div class='menu-content'>
        <ul class='menu-list'>
            <li>
                <a href='' class='menu-link title'>About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='' class='menu-link title'>Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='' class='menu-link title'>Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<button id='burger'>Burger</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it does not work as smooth-scrollbar.js creates a scroll that isnt on the body.